# how to display a fileexception in flashbag (try/catch)?

Tags: symfony4

i have a problem with an exception that i want to display through a flashbag in Symfony 4. I tried several things without result.

```
    $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension(); 

    try {

         $file->move($this->getParameter('file_directory'), $fileName);

    } 

    catch (FileException $exception) {

    *** How to display the FileException in a flashbag ?***

    }
```

In my twig file, i have this :

```
    {# UploadFile Error message #}
    {% for flash_message in app.session.flashbag.get('UploadFileError') %}
        <div class="container text-center alert alert-danger mt-5 mb-5 font-weight-bold">
            {{ flash_message }} <span class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></span>
         </div>    
    {% endfor %}
```

And i added this too :

```
    {# UploadFile Error #}
    {% if error is defined %}
        {% if error %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger mb-5 font-weight-bold" role="alert">
                {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }} <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
        {% endif %} 
    {% endif %}
```

But the error only appears in the debug bar even though I'm doing in the controller.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Without autowiring you can do:

```php
try {
    $file->move($this->getParameter('file_directory'), $fileName);
} catch (FileException $exception) {
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', $exception->getMessage());
}
```

If autowiring is enable (prefered way) pass the `FlashBagInterface` object as parameter of method or constructor

```php
/**
 * @param FlashBagInterface $bag
 */
public function checkFile(FlashBagInterface $bag)
{
    $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

    try {
        $file->move($this->getParameter('file_directory'), $fileName);
    } catch (FileException $exception) {
        $bag->add('error', $exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then in your twig

```
{% for label, messages in app.flashes(['error']) %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ label }}">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

For more informations: [Flash Messages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#flash-messages)